# How to download large data from a SQL table and consecutively save into csv by fetching 1000 or so records at once

Tags: python, mysql, csv, dataframe, large-data

I have a SQL table consisting of 10 million rows and lot of columns, The table size when queried is around 44 GB.

However I am trying to fetch only 3 columns from this table and save it into csv / load into dataframe the python keeps running forever.
i.e

```
 pd.read_sql("select a,b,c from table") is taking more than 1 hour and not returning data
```

```
How to achieve this? Can I load this entire data in dataframe at once is that a viable option.
After this I should be able to perform some data manipulations on these rows.

2. OR should I download this to csv and read this data part by part to in-memory.
```

If its 2. How to code for 2?

Code tried for 2 so far is :

```
   def iter_row(cursor, size=10):
while True:
    rows = cursor.fetchmany(size)
    if not rows:
        break
    for row in rows:
        yield row

  def query_with_fetchmany():

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM books")

    for row in iter_row(cursor, 10):
        print(row)
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: Perhaps you can do more of the processing in the database and less in the dataframe.

Comment: Would nt in-memory operation in the dataframe be quicker than Mysql

Comment: Have you tried just using the `mysql` command-line tool? `mysql -Be QUERY` outputs results in tab-separated format.

Answer (score 4):

you can read data in chunks:

```
for c in pd.read_sql("select a,b,c from table", con=connection, chunksize=10**5):
    c.to_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv', index=False, mode='a')
```

Comment: It has been 10 mins since I started this query and the space used by python is already gone beyond 1.2 GB, It is still not writing the csv file in the folder? Shouldnt it already be writing this

Comment: @Viv, this is weird. Try to reduce the `chunksize`

Comment: Nope, I reduced to 10^2 and re ran, now again its using 1.2 gb and no csv generation yet. What is missing here?

Comment: what happens if you execute `select a,b,c from table limit 1000` using `mysql` client from the same machine/server where your Python script is running?

Comment: Oh thats pretty fast. thats why i am worried

Comment: @Viv, i'm afraid i would need a reproducible environment in  order to be able to help :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145216/discussion-between-viv-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1):

I searched and experimented with many different methods of doing this and found that the `fetchmany` approach worked the best -- there were no RAM or CPU issues when downloading database tables >10GB in size on a laptop with only 8GB of RAM. It also allows you to view the progress of your query.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import csv

csv_path = 'file.csv'
csv_columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sql_string = text("""select a, b, c from table_name;""")
batch_size = 50_000 # 50_000 rows worked best for me, ymmv
db_url = 'db_type:db_api://user:pwd@server:port/database'

engine = create_engine(db_url)
with engine.connect() as conn:

    with open(csv_path, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        c = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        c.writerow(csv_columns)
        result = conn.execute(sql_string)
        counter = 1
        while True:
            print(f'Fetch # {counter}')
            rows = result.fetchmany(batch_size)
            if not rows:
                break
            for row in rows:
                c.writerow(row)
            counter += 1
        result.close()
```